# Auth on AngularFire and Firebase gives "This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on"

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have this error...

> Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

when i run...

```
$scope.authRef  = $firebaseAuth();
$scope.authRef.$signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Signed in as:", result.user.uid);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Authentication failed:", error);
});
```

the previous code works only on Google Chrome (*for macOS version 59.0.3071.115*) but doesn't on Safari or Firefox (*for PC*) and Google Chrome and Safari for iOS or Android devices.

**Does anyone know what the problem is?**

*Current config*

- AngularJS 1.6.4
- Firebase 4.1.3
- Angularfire 2.3.0
- Auth provider (for Google) enable on Firebase console

Comment: Are you running in private/incognito mode? Are your cookies/web storage disabled?

Comment: You're right, thank you so much. Now, on mobile devices (Google Chrome and Safari for iOS) the process is interrupted and shows a new error: The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation. But the popup it is closed by itself. Any idea?